# How to Include File from Plugins into Template?

Tags: plugins, themes

I need to include a file from plugin Folder in my template file. How can I do that? Is there any other way to do that rather than:

```
include('../../..');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plugins_url( 'file_location/relative_to.plugin', 'plugin/file/location' );`, or something along those lines at least, should do it for you. Alternatively, you could work from the top down and say something like `include( '/wp-content/plugins/you-plugin-name/file.php' )` to get it, whichever is easier.